# SSH a user inside docker container

Tags: docker, ssh

I would like to know if it is possible to use ssh over a container in order to access a local user (over the same container).
"ssh user@localhost"
I used ssh-keygen to generate a new key over root and over user. Also i copied the root public key towards the authorized-keys file of user but this isn’t working.
Also i changed the SSH keys permissions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of errors do you have ?

Comment: It is not an error. It keeps asking for a password and even if i put the correct password that doesn’t work. Also i noticed that it is not possible to use ssh if we launch the container with the default bridge network (since i got a message network is unreachable). While with host network it keeps asking for pass.

Answer (score 0):

You can get command line access to the docker container from the machine it's running on by using

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash
```

You can get the container id with `docker ps`

Once on the machine you should be able to change users with `su - username`